# How can I split a string with a JavaScript regex?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to split this string into kind of a structure,

```
20:33:15     From Deekshitha Oku : Me too
```

into

```
{ time: "20:33:15", name: "Deekshitha Oku", message: "Me too" }
```

So for that, I wrote a Regex,

```
(([0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])(.*?)(From)\s(.*?).:\s(.*?).+
```

But it's not what I expecting, it wired here. What I expect is something like this,

```
[
  "20:33:15",
  "Deekshitha Oku",
  "Me too"
]
```

```js
const match = "20:33:15     From Deekshitha Oku : Me too".match(/(([0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])(.*?)(From)\s(.*?).:\s(.*?).+/);

console.log(match);
```

What is the issue with this regex, I was tried many different ways :(

Comment: You have too many capture groups in your regex. Each time you use a new set of parentheses, you create a new capture group, and thus a new result in your regex result. Instead, use non capturing groups starting with `(?:` except for when you actually want the content inside that capture group to be returned to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change your regex to this:

```
^((?:[0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]).*?From\s(.*?).:\s(.*).+$
```

Then you can generate the object:

```js
const match = "20:33:15     From Deekshitha Oku : Me too".match(/^((?:[0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]).*?From\s(.*?).:\s(.*).+$/);
const object = { time: match[1], name: match[2], message: match[3] };

console.log(object);
```

---

EDIT: Using named capture groups, you can just use `match.name` etc. and don't have to generate a new object:

```js
const match = "20:33:15     From Deekshitha Oku : Me too".match(/^(?<time>(?:[0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]).*?From\s(?<name>.*?).:\s(?<message>.*)$/).groups;

console.log(match);
```

Note the added `.groups` after the match call.

Comment: Anyhow above regex skips the last character, so I found this working `^(?<time>(?:[0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]).*?From\s(?<name>.*?).:\s*(?<message>.*$)$`

Comment: Yeah, my fault, I fixed it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't split, put your captures into named capture groups:

```
(?<time>^.{1,8}) *From (?<person>[^:]+?)(?= *:) *: *(?<message>.*$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/BAMv5K/1

```js
console.log(/(?<time>^.{1,8}) *From (?<person>[^:]+?)(?= *:) *: *(?<message>.*$)/.exec(`20:33:15     From Deekshitha Oku : Me too`).groups)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need some small tweaks:

```js
/((?:[0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])\s*From\s*([^:]*):\s*(.*)/
```

First, don't use parens when you don't want to capture the information (like you had around From).  Second, use `(?:)` instead of `()` if you just want the parens for grouping, not for capturing.  Third, non-greedy matches are more complicated and error-prone than a construct like `[^:]*` (in my opinion).  Saying "match all not-colon" is more explicit.

See https://regex101.com/r/3dLjbV/1 to play with my attempt at your problem.